# Create Object as Couponbonds class

Tags: r, class

Using the termstrc package, I would like to create my own dataset of U.S. bond prices to predict the term structure. I have been using YieldCurve to do this, with some success, but would like to try other methods provided by termstrc. The issue is that termstrc only deals with couponbonds class. How would I create a couponbonds class object with up-to-date data??

Answer (score 1):

`?govbonds` tells you how to do this:

> ```
> If you use your own data set, make sure that the structure is
>  identical to the provided data sets. Use the function ‘str()’ to
>  explore the data set.
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  data(govbonds)
>  str(govbonds) 
>
>  # The following code may be used to generate an empty data set,
>  # which can then be filled with bond data:
>
>  ISIN <- vector()
>  MATURITYDATE <- vector()
>  ISSUEDATE <- vector()
>  COUPONRATE <- vector()
>  PRICE <- vector()
>  ACCRUED <- vector()
>
>  CFISIN <- vector()
>  CF <- vector()
>  DATE <- vector()
>
>  CASHFLOWS <- list(CFISIN,CF,DATE)
>  names(CASHFLOWS) <- c("ISIN","CF","DATE")
>
>  TODAY <- vector()
>
>  mycountry1 <- list(ISIN,MATURITYDATE,ISSUEDATE,
>                     COUPONRATE,PRICE,ACCRUED,CASHFLOWS,TODAY)
>  mycountry2 <- list(ISIN,MATURITYDATE,ISSUEDATE,
>                     COUPONRATE,PRICE,ACCRUED,CASHFLOWS,TODAY)
>
>  names(mycountry1) <- c("ISIN","MATURITYDATE","ISSUEDATE","COUPONRATE",
>                         "PRICE","ACCRUED","CASHFLOWS","TODAY")
>  names(mycountry2) <- c("ISIN","MATURITYDATE","ISSUEDATE","COUPONRATE",
>                         "PRICE","ACCRUED","CASHFLOWS","TODAY")
>
>  mybonds <- list(mycountry1,mycountry2)
>
>  names(mybonds) <- c("mycountry1","mycountry2")
>  class(mybonds) <- "couponbonds"
> ```

Comment: Ah ok, I read this but didn't interpret it correctly.